# kubernetes dashboard showing http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I installed kubeadm to deploy multi node kubernetes cluster. Added two nodes. Those are ready. I am able to run my app using node port service. While i am trying yo access the dashboard facing an issue.
I am following the steps to install dashboard in this [link](http://www.assistanz.com/steps-to-install-kubernetes-dashboard/)

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

dash-admin.yaml:
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
   name: kubernetes-dashboard
   labels:
     k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
   name: kubernetes-dashboard
   namespace: kube-system

kubectl create -f dashboard-admin.yaml

nohup kubectl proxy --address="172.20.22.101" -p 443 --accept-hosts='^*$' &
```

Its running well and saving the output in `nohup.out`

When i try to access the site using the url: `172.20.22.101:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/….` it's showing `connection refused`. 
I observed the output in the `nohup.out`, it's showing the below error:

> I1203 12:28:05.880828 15591 log.go:172] http: proxy error: dial tcp
>   [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused –

Comment: check your DNS settings. what's in /etc/resolv.conf in your dashboard pod? can you reach it? (to check, run `kubectl exec <podname> -- cat /etc/resolv.conf`)

Comment: You need to provide more config details.

Comment: pod status showing ContainerCreating.

Comment: kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-v6l2h   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          21h

Comment: Post output of `kubectl describe kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-v6l2h`

Answer (score 3):

You are not running it with root or sudo permission.

I have encountered this issue, and after running using root. I was able to access it with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
log.go:172] http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused –
```

In case anyone comes across the above issue, know that this error occurs when one tries to hit Kubernetes API without proper permission.

> Note: Its nothing to do with RBAC.

To solve this issue, I took below steps

1. Check access. Execute as root.
2. In case you are using **kubectl proxy** to connect to Kubernetes API, make sure kubeconfig file is properly configured. or try **kubectl proxy --kubeconfig=/path/to/dashboard-user.kubeconfig**

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, turns out the terminal instance I was running `kubectl proxy` in didn't have `KUBECONFIG` exported - changed the terminal and it ran smooth as butter

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem this days and root cause of problem is that in cluster deployment (3 nodes), kuberenetes dashboard pod was up on the slave (non master) node.
Issue is that proxy is provided only locally (security reasons),
so dashboard console could not be started on master, neither node 3!

On master node browser error (kubectl proxy & executed on this node):

```
"http: proxy error: dial tcp 10.32.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused"
```

On slave node error (kubectl proxy & executed on this node):

```
 "http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused"
```

**Solution:**

Status of the cluster pods showed that dashboard pod kubernetes-dashboard-7b544877d5-lj4xq 
 was on node 3:

namespace   kubernetes-dashboard 
pod     kubernetes-dashboard-7b544877d5-lj4xq 
node        pb-kn-node03

```
[root@PB-KN-Node01 ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide|more <br>
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES <br>
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-ph7cc                     1/1     Running   1          3d17h   10.32.0.3      pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-x22cv                     1/1     Running   1          3d17h   10.32.0.2      pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            etcd-pb-kn-node01                            1/1     Running   2        3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-pb-kn-node01                  1/1     Running   2          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-pb-kn-node01         1/1     Running   3          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-proxy-4ngd2                             1/1     Running   2          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-proxy-7qvbj                             1/1     Running   0          3d12h   10.13.40.202   pb-kn-node02   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-proxy-fgrcp                             1/1     Running   0          3d12h   10.13.40.203   pb-kn-node03   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-pb-kn-node01                  1/1     Running   3          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            weave-net-fm2kd                              2/2     Running   5          3d12h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            weave-net-l6rmw                              2/2     Running   1          3d12h   10.13.40.203   pb-kn-node03   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            weave-net-r56xk                              2/2     Running   1          3d12h   10.13.40.202   pb-kn-node02   <none>           <none> <br>
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-6b4884c9d5-v2gqp   1/1     Running   0          2d22h   10.40.0.1      pb-kn-node02   <none>           <none> 
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-7b544877d5-lj4xq        1/1     Running   15         2d22h   10.32.0.2      pb-kn-node03   <none>           <none>
```

**So all active global pods are reallocated from node 3 (included dashboard)
to master node after draining the node**

**[root@PB-KN-Node01 ~]# kubectl  drain --delete-local-data  --ignore-daemonsets  pb-kn-node03** 
node/pb-kn-node03 already cordoned 
WARNING: ignoring DaemonSet-managed Pods: kube-system/kube-proxy-fgrcp, kube-system/weave-net-l6rmw 
node/pb-kn-node03 drained

After 2 miniutes ...

```
[root@PB-KN-Node01 ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide|more <br>
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES <br>
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-ph7cc                     1/1     Running   1          3d17h   10.32.0.3      pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            coredns-66bff467f8-x22cv                     1/1     Running   1          3d17h   10.32.0.2      pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            etcd-pb-kn-node01                            1/1     Running   2          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-apiserver-pb-kn-node01                  1/1     Running   2          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-pb-kn-node01         1/1     Running   3          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-proxy-4ngd2                             1/1     Running   2          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-proxy-7qvbj                             1/1     Running   0          3d12h   10.13.40.202   pb-kn-node02   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-proxy-fgrcp                             1/1     Running   0          3d12h   10.13.40.203   pb-kn-node03   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            kube-scheduler-pb-kn-node01                  1/1     Running   3          3d17h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            weave-net-fm2kd                              2/2     Running   5          3d12h   10.13.40.201   pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            weave-net-l6rmw                              2/2     Running   1          3d12h   10.13.40.203   pb-kn-node03   <none>           <none> <br>
kube-system            weave-net-r56xk                              2/2     Running   1          3d12h   10.13.40.202   pb-kn-node02   <none>           <none> 
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-6b4884c9d5-v2gqp   1/1     Running   0          2d22h   10.40.0.1      pb-kn-node02   <none>           <none> <br>
<b>kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-7b544877d5-8ln2n        1/1     Running   0          89s     10.32.0.4      pb-kn-node01   <none>           <none> </b><br>
```

And the problem was solved, kubernetes dashboard was available on master node.